# PHP/MYSQL with google maps

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I need to extract data from MySQL table and create markers to be displayed on google map.

### **PHP Code for outputting xml**

```
<?php

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
    return $xmlStr; 
} 

$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('data1', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM health_block";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<markers>';

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<marker ';
    echo 'Hname="' . parseToXML($row['Hname']) . '" ';
    echo 'Lat="' . $row['Lat'] . '" ';
    echo 'Longt="' . $row['Longt'] . '" ';
    echo '/>';
}
echo '</markers>';
?>
```

Below is the output that I get with the above code. (The code outputs all records from database table):

```
<markers>
<marker Hname="CHC Anchuthengu" Lat="8.6734310" Longt="76.7581770"/>
<marker Hname="PHC Perumathura" Lat="8.6218640" Longt="76.7975220"/>
<marker Hname="PHC Keezhattingal" Lat="8.6982130" Longt="76.7915000"/>
<marker Hname="PHC Azhoor" Lat="8.6408080" Longt="76.8252470"/>

</markers>
```

### **PHP Main page for displaying the markers in google map**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.491118,76.949840),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var hname = markers[i].getAttribute("Hname");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longt")));
          var html = "<b>" + hname + "</b>";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
           });
           bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };
      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    //]]>

  </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="load()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 1400px; height: 800px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

While executing this code in browser, it displays the google map correctly. But my markers are not shown. It would be great if you could help.

Thanks
Jeny

Comment: Did you ever heard about `json` ? I believe that is a better approach for your case.

Comment: Anyway, your code will only work in Internet Explorer because of your xml http object type. Consider using `jQuery` for that purpose.

Comment: That isn't true. `var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;` works in other browsers besides IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this error in IE:

```
Message: 'type' is undefined
Line: 38
Char: 7
Code: 0
```

This in Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined v3_SO_PHPMySQL.html:38
```

If I fix that (by defining it `var type = "bar";`), I see markers.

```
    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(8.491118,76.949840),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      downloadUrl("SO_phpsqlajax_genxml_20130731.xml", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var hname = markers[i].getAttribute("Hname");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longt")));
      var html = "<b>" + hname + "</b>";
      var type = "bar";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_PHPMySQL.html)

Comment: how do i allow user to mark his location as input **Eg:** i have a form and goolge map will track location of user and user has to mark his location with marker by click and lat/long should be saved to `SQL`

Comment: comments are not the appropriate place to ask new questions. Please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: but i tried above code it doesn't show my location, It shows some other country

Comment: Still not an appropriate comment.  Ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), referencing this one, with a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: but if i ask new question user will mark as duplicate

Comment: Then make sure it isn't a duplicate before you ask it.

Comment: this answer doesn't address the issue.. the OP had a PHP script which was copied direct from Google documentation (I should know, doing it now haha) but it returns xml is undefined - the above answer uses an XML script..

Comment: He had a typo in his copy of the script (as might you if you are getting the same error)